# Заголовок страницы, изменяющийся через AJAX запрос

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, веб-программирование, веб-дизайн

Возникла такая проблема. Сайт отправляет AJAX запрос, получая информацию (имя, фамилия и т.д.), и сразу меняет заголовок страницы на "Имя Фамилия".

Проблема заключается в том, что **другие сайты(вк и т.д.) видят только первоначальный заголовок страницы**, а мне нужен **изменённый AJAX запросов, заголовок страницы.**

AJAX запрос отправляется синхронно.

Изменение заголовка происходит так: `document.title = founded.name + " " + founded.surname`

P.S. ещё я использую Vue.js, может пригодится :d

Comment: --другие сайты видят-- это как